# WordPress on IIS, Issues with WP_Query()

Tags: wordpress

I have a client who has WordPress installed on IIS (php5, fast cgi) and is having an issue with my menu not showing up. Ironically, if he reverts to my previous theme version, the menu shows fine. Since I changed the query between the two versions, I'm wondering if someone might be able to spot the problem in the latter.

Previous version query appears to work fine:

```
    global $post;
    $cat=get_cat_ID('top-menu');
    $catHidden=get_cat_ID('hidden');
    $count=0;
    $mypostsheader = get_posts(array('cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden",'showposts' => $cb2_current_count));
    $mypostsheader2 = get_posts(array('cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden",'showposts' => -1));
    $mypostsheadercount = count($mypostsheader2);

    if($mypostsheader)
    {
    $current_page = get_post( $current_page );
    ?>
```

However, the current version uses a bit different code logic to build the menu. This does not work under the same setup (but works on Apache fine)

```
 $cat=get_cat_ID('top-menu'); 
 $catHidden=get_cat_ID('hidden');
 $myqueryTopMenu = new WP_Query();
 $myqueryTopMenu->query(array(
  'cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden",
  'post_not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts')
 ));
 $mypostsheadercount = $myqueryTopMenu->found_posts;

 if($mypostsheadercount > 0)
 {
 global $post;
 $mypostsheader = get_posts(array('cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden",'showposts' => $cb2_current_count));
 $current_page = get_post( $current_page );
 ?>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What errors do you get?

Comment: No errors, the menu does not get written to the browser in example 2, however in example 1 it does. This only presents on this particular installation, which happens to be running in IIS. I've narrowed it to the if($mypostsheadercount > 0) code block. If I change the test to >= it works fine, so my issue is apparently in getting that variable calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how IIS is affecting this - are you sure both environments are running the same WordPress version?

I also recommend using `posts_per_page` over `showposts` - as mentioned in the documentation, `showposts` is deprecated, and could be completely removed in the near future.

Comment: After some further testing, I found that it if I change the if($mypostsheadercount > 0) to '>=' the menu gets written. So, apparently there's an issue with getting that count variable in IIS.

Comment: BTW, I changed to posts_per_page. He's running WordPress 3.0